# Problema com Slider

Tags: css, wordpress

Quando carrega a página [desse site](http://www.inpacto.org.br/novosite/) o título da descrição do *slider* aparece no topo e depois desce.

Como resolver?

O site está em WordPress. Plugin Huge IT Slider

Acredito que o problema talvez seja de CSS.

Comment: Que eu saiba isso acontece quando tem um elemento vazio que recebe conteúdo e o `height` aumenta de repente. Se a altura é fixa, é fácil resolver, se for variável são outros 500.

Answer (score 1):

Verifique se você possuí algum script com `$(document).load(function())` ou `$(window).load(function())` e altere para `$(document).ready(function())`. É claro, altere apenas os elementos que correspondem o ID ou Class de gatilho da sua função.

Acredito que o problema não seja no CSS.

Um problema do CSS é a frase "Mais de 150 trabalhadores são resgatados no Piauí" que está sobrepondo o campo "Notícias"

Comment: Acho que ele deve procurar o ID ou Class que chama esse slider e jogar dentro do `$(document).ready(function())`, se ele simplesmente mudar, pode comprometer outros elementos do site, não?

Comment: Alterei mas continua a mesma coisa. A impressão que tenho que alterando o load p ready o carregamento fica mais rápido.

Comment: @FelipeStoker sim, de fato. Deveria ter adicionado essa linha em minha resposta, algo que farei.

Comment: @kadupereira não sei se foi a minha solução que pra produção mas, seu site está abrindo corretamente aqui agora.

Comment: Obrigado @RafaelBarbosa fiz a alteração que você indicou no post. $(window).load(function()) por $(document).ready(function()).